# VS2010 to show summary info from parent interfaces/class in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I want to know if there is any method to show summary info from parent interfaces/class in IntelliSense.

Let's say, I have an interface `IMyInterface` and a class `MyClass`

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    ///<summary>
    /// This is just a testing method
    ///</summary>
    void MyMethod();
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public void MyMethod() { /* do nothing */ }
}
```

The problem I facing is for every method, I need to copy the summary tags from parent interfaces or abstract class **manually** in order that I want to have information show in IntelliSense when I was using MyClass. That makes me very inconvenient.

So I am seeking help...... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the interface if you want intellisense and don't want to copy the documentation.

```
IMyInterface instance = new MyClass();
instance.MyMethod(); // shows intellisense
```

Some tool like [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/AdvEditing/altInsertOver.html) offer you to copy the documentation when implementing a interface. Cheers